# Why is the upstream command called SO many times?

Tags: powershell

Currently, I'm writing a PowerShell module which automatically configures aliases for all git commands, inspired by [git-sh](https://github.com/rtomayko/git-sh).

Then I wrote functions below.
The `Enable-GitAliases` function is the entry point to configure aliases automatically.
it collects git's subcommands by `Get-GitCommands`, which parses `git --help -a` to get all git's subcommands.
Then it defines the wrapper functions for the collected git commands.

**My question is**: why is `git --help -a` called so many times (possibly infinitely) when invoking `Enable-GitAliases`, which causing significant slow down?

After writing the code, I found `Enable-GitAliases` takes too much time (I've never seen it finishes).
According to the Task Manager, the `git --help -a` command is launched and exits repeatedly.
I expected the `git --help -a` command is called only once.
Actually, `Get-GitCommands | % { echo $_ }` calls `git --help -a` only once.
What is the difference, and what is best way to fix?

```
function Get-GitCommands {
  -Split (git --help -a | select-string -pattern '^  [-a-zA-Z0-9.]+\s*')
}

function Enable-GitAliases($avoidConflicts = $true) {
  Get-GitCommands | % {
    $aliasName = $_
    if (-not ($avoidConflicts -and (Get-Command $aliasName 2> $null) -ne $null)) {
      Enable-GitAliases $aliasName
    }
  }
}

function Enable-GitAlias($commandName) {
  $wrapper = @'
    function global:{0} {{
      git {0} $args
    }}
'@ -f $commandName
  Invoke-Expression $wrapper
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `Enable-GitAliases` recursively, but is this intended?

Is your intention this?

```
function Enable-GitAliases($avoidConflicts = $true) {
  Get-GitCommands | % {
    $aliasName = $_
    if (-not ($avoidConflicts -and (Get-Command $aliasName 2> $null) -ne $null)) {
      # Enable-GitAliases -> Enable-GitAlias
      Enable-GitAlias $aliasName
    }
  }
}
```